# Increasing the height of footline in a beamer slide

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am using the following to customise my footline, but it does not seem to change the height of the footline. What am I missing

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{ 
 \leavevmode%
\makebox[\paperwidth]
{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1.5cm, leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fill]{author in head/foot}%
   {\large \url{www.yahoo.com}}
 \end{beamercolorbox}%

}%
 \vskip0pt%
}
```

Comment: While code snippets are helpful, it is best to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. To do so, [`edit` your post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/39185/edit) and add the relevant content.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `\fontsize{size}{skip}` command, where `size` is your desired fontsize, and `skip` is the distance between lines (multiplied by `\baselineskip`)

```
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
```

The height of `footline` is computed to fit the font. Is this what you want?